# Why won't my cp command copy whole directories?

Tags: command-line, cp

I've tested the `cp` command, and it will only copy individual files. For example, I typed `cp` followed by the exact filename, then typed the directory and the file got copied. However, when I typed the directory and the destination directory, nothing on the computer changed. I thought `cp` was supposed to copy contents in the directories.

I've tried this multiple times.

Comment: I can't believe I can't find a duplicate for this: to copy a folder, you have to use the `-R` option: `cp -R /source/path /target/path`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you use **cp** without any arguments, it defaults to copying files as below

```
 cp sourcefile destinationLocation
 #will copy sourcefile to the specified destinationLocation
```

But if you want to copy a directory, you need to specify the recursive argument like this

```
cp -R dir1 dir2 #copies dir1 to dir2
cp -R dir dir2 dir3 #copies dir1 & dir2 to dir3
```

Ideally you can specify as many files as you want to a single destination all separated by spaces. This here below however copies a dir along with its permissions

```
 sudo cp -rp /home/me /media/backup/me
 -p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
```

**Alternatively you can use rsync**

```
 sudo rsync -a /home/me/ /media/backup/me/
 -a, --archive

          Note that -a does not preserve hardlinks, because finding  multiply-linked
          files is expensive.  You must separately specify -H.
```

And Please don't forget the trailing slashes when copying using rsync. See the man page for each command on options of using them available on your terminal by typing **man cp** or **man rsync**

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
cp -R
```

It specifies recursive copy i.e. all sub-directories and files will be copied.
Use `man cp` to find more switches for cp.

Comment: `-R, -r, --recursive` are the same you know

Answer (score 0):

`cp` does not, by default, copy directories. From [`man 1posix cp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cp.1posix.html):

```
2. If source_file is of type directory, the following steps  shall  be
   taken:

    a. If  neither the -R or -r options were specified, cp shall write
       a diagnostic message to standard error, do  nothing  more  with
       source_file, and go on to any remaining files.
```

You should have got a message like so:

```
cp: omitting directory '...'
```

For example:

```
$ cp Documents Pictures
cp: omitting directory ‘Documents’
```

As can be seen from the manpage, use `-r` or `-R` with `cp`:

```
cp -R Documents Pictures
```